# How to open the Windows Terminal Preview in File Explorer with normal version also installed

Tags: windows-terminal

This is the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1481203/how-to-open-the-windows-terminal-preview-in-file-explorer), but I want to open the Preview version when I have both Preview and the normal version installed.

What I'm looking for is a shortcut like `wtp`, or `wt --preview`, something that differentiates it from the normal version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find `Windows Terminal Preview` in search.
2. Create shortcut and rename to `wtp`.
3. Put shortcut in PATH.

It's gonna be `wtp.lnk` though :/ And it's going to open in `c/Windows/system32` despite giving `wtp.lnk -d .` a go.

[This microsoft blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1-1-release/) suggests to use [this tutorial](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-app-execution-aliases-windows-10) to remove the normal version's alias and use the preview for `wt` alias. Not perfect.