# Opening file location in Ubuntu with Windows Terminal Preview

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-preview

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1481203/how-to-open-the-windows-terminal-preview-in-file-explorer) article very helpful but would find it really useful to be able to do the same with an Ubuntu tab in WTP. Is this possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can normally run Windows Terminal Preview with `wt`, then it shouldn't be a problem.  If you have both the released version *and* Preview installed, then you'll need to change which one is assigned to `wt.exe` through the *"Manage App Execution Aliases"* settings in Windows.

You'll also need to:

- Set your default Windows Terminal Profile to be Ubuntu.  This is through the drop-down menu, *Settings* -> *Startup* tab -> *Default Profile*
- Then, under the settings for that profile, make sure *"Use parent process directory"* is selected for the *"Starting directory"*.

That should allow you to launch into Ubuntu using the technique described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1485021/1210833).  Just type `wt` in File Explorer in a directory, and it should launch into it in Ubuntu.

Note that this will work for any *Windows* path or path in `\\wsl$\Ubuntu` (assuming that's your distro name), but it will not work for *other* distributions under `\\wsl$\`.

Comment: Turns out I was opening the wrong "Ubuntu" distro in WTP but with this answer and the right distro it's now working! Thanks!